# Symfony does not read the base path propely after url rewrite

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

I've rewritten all urls from `/api/(.*)$` to `/api/public/index.php/$1` using this nginx configuration:

```
location /api/ {
    try_files $uri @rewriteindex;
}
location @rewriteindex {
    rewrite ^/api/(.*)$ /api/public/index.php/$1 last;
}
location ~ ^/api/public/index\.php(/|$) {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $path_info;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
}
```

Everything works as expected but when I navigate to `/api/something` (propely mapped to `/api/public/index.php/something`), symfony is searching for `/api/something/` route instead of `something`, and consequently triggering an error because the route does not exists.
**How to let symfony get routes relative to `/api/` folder?**